# Declare a variable with a select statement - PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

Is there a way to declare a variable with a select statement? Below is an example.

```
  Declare
P_Price orders.p_price%type;
  Begin 
    P_Price := (select price from products where p_id = 1000);
```

Look up price in a table to declare the price

Answer (score 0):

You declare a variable in the declaration section (between `declare` and `begin` in an anonymous PL/SQL block).  You seem to be asking about assigning a value to that variable.  You do that with a `select into`.

```
select price
  into p_price
  from products
 where p_id = 1000;
```

If the query returns anything other than 1 row, you'll get an exception.  `no_data_found` if the query returns 0 rows and `too_many_rows` if the query returns more than 1 row.

If you want the full anonymous block (including the declaration section that you already had unchanged)

```
declare
  p_price products.price%type;
begin
  select price
    into p_price
    from products
   where p_id = 1000;
end;
```

Comment: I've tried this but it keeps returning the below error:                          into p_price
       *

ERROR at line 2: 
 ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: @JRock - What is the code that you are actually running?  The snippet I posted would go between the `begin` and `end` in your block in place of your assignment statement.   You'd still need the declaration section.

Comment: This is what I'm trying below to auto find the prices for each product be searching the P_ID:Declare
 P_Price orders.p_price%type;
    
Begin
    P_Price := select price into p_price from products where p_id = 1000;    
        P_Price := select price into p_price from products where p_id = 1000;
               *

ERROR at line 28: 
 ORA-06550: line 28, column 16: 
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: 
 ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>

Comment: @JRock - What you posted in your comment doesn't have the change I suggested.  As I said, I was just replacing the body of your block not the declaration section.  I updated my question to include the complete anonymous block if you're struggling to incorporate the select statement I suggested into your existing anonymous block.